# sitemap.xml not showing up in production

Tags: xml, aws-amplify, sitemap

I am building a Typescript and React app and I am trying to add a sitemap.xml to my site. When I go to the /sitemap.xml endpoint when running on localhost, it returns the sitemap. But when I push to production on AWS Amplify and I go to the endpoint (https://wordle.latindictionary.io/sitemap.xml), it returns the homepage.

I have the sitemap.xml in my public directory, here is a link to a screenshot of the file structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh0Fb.png

Here is my XML file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWNCw.png

As I mentioned earlier, I am hosting the site via AWS Amplify and even when I run the production build on localhost it still returns the sitemap. Also, if you go to this endpoint https://wordle.latindictionary.io/favicon.ico it returns the favicon. So I am not sure why images and other items in the public folder would be returned and not the sitemap.xml.

Hopefully, there is an easy fix to this and not something wrong with Amplify.

Thanks,
Theo

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. My solution was to change the redirect settings in AWS Amplify to allow file types ending in `.xml` to be returned and not forwarded to the root URL (/).

This means adding adding `xml` to this rule `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(xml|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`.

Comment: for me this meant adding xml to this rule

</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(xml|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>