# I'm Deploying and web app in amplify with Angular 15 but the sitemap.xml is not working

Tags: angular, angular15

I'm deploying a web page in Angular 15 but the sitemap.xml is not working but robots.txt is working.

[image]

when I run ng serve http://localhost:4200/sitemap.xml it's works ok, and I don't have any issue with that but when I make the deploy in Amplify not works and redirect to the index.html and show me the next

[image]

this is my configuration in angular.json

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/emermedica-front/browser",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/robots.txt",
          "src/sitemap.xml"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.sass"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },

"server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/emermedica-front/server",
        "main": "server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/robots.txt",
          "src/sitemap.xml"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sitemap.xml not showing up in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887687/sitemap-xml-not-showing-up-in-production)